# Can I turn off auto-indent tab coloring in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2

When auto-indent is active in Sublime Text 2, tabs which are inserted automatically are colored – in the Monokai color scheme, they're purple. What is this setting called, so I can disable it?

[image]

Comment: I could not replicate this.
So you can either search in `Preferences -> Settings - Default` what's doing this, or try ST3 if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it – it wasn't a setting at all, but some kind of glitch. Here's how I fixed it:

I checked the color of the highlighted tab with a color picker, then searched for that color in the scheme file. It was used in a few places, so I just changed each instance to another color until I changed the tab color.

Turns out it was:

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
    <string>Invalid deprecated</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>invalid.deprecated</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
      <key>background</key>
      <string>#AE81FF</string>
```

...I'm guessing it had something to do with the way my yaml syntax definitions were interpreting the auto-indents.